# how to use pytorch accuracy metric in a loop?

Tags: python, function, loops, pytorch

I am trying to substitute the manually defined accuracy function such as this:

```
def accuracy(model, x, y):
    out = model(x)
    correct = torch.abs(y - out) < 0.5
    return correct.float().mean()
```

for a pytorch in-build accuracy function:

```
accuracy_fn = BinaryAccuracy(threshold=0.5)
```

I have the encrypted_evaluation function like this:

```
class EncryptedLR:
    
    def __init__(self, torch_lr):
        # TenSEAL processes lists and not torch tensors,
        self.weight = torch_lr.lr.weight.data.tolist()[0]
        self.bias = torch_lr.lr.bias.data.tolist()
        
    def forward(self, enc_x):
        enc_out = enc_x.dot(self.weight) + self.bias
        return enc_out
    
    def plain_accuracy(self, x_test_f, y_test_f):
        # evaluate accuracy of the model on
        # the plain (x_test, y_test) dataset 
        w = torch.tensor(self.weight)
        b = torch.tensor(self.bias)
        out = torch.sigmoid(x_test_f.matmul(w) + b).reshape(-1, 1)

        acc = acc_fn(out, y_test_f)
        return acc
    
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.forward(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def encrypt(self, context):
        self.weight = ts.ckks_vector(context, self.weight)
        self.bias = ts.ckks_vector(context, self.bias)
        
    def decrypt(self, context):
        self.weight = self.weight.decrypt()
        self.bias = self.bias.decrypt()

eelr = EncryptedLR(model) # an EncryptedLR class instance

# eelr.plain_accuracy(x_test, y_test)  # this works fine.
# tensor(0.5270)

def encrypted_evaluation(model, enc_x_test, y_test):
    t_start = time()
    
    correct = 0
    for enc_x, y in zip(enc_x_test, y_test):
        # encrypted evaluation
        enc_out = model(enc_x)
   
        out = enc_out.decrypt()
        out = torch.tensor(out)
        out = torch.sigmoid(out)
        acc = accuracy_fn(out, y)  
#        if torch.abs(out - y) < 0.5:   # this works
#            correct += 1
              
    t_end = time()

#    print(f"Accuracy: {correct}/{len(x_test)} = {correct / len(x_test)}")
#    return correct / len(x_test_f)

    print(f"Accuracy: {acc}")
    return acc


encrypted_accuracy = encrypted_evaluation(eelr, enc_x_test, y_test)

print("encrypted_accuracy:", encrypted_accuracy)
```

when I am substituting these two lines,

```
if torch.abs(out - y) < 0.5:   
     correct += 1
```

with this line,

```
acc = accuracy_fn(out, y)
```

It does not work because the accuracy is calculated as 0.00.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

The original reproducible code is from here, https://github.com/OpenMined/TenSEAL/blob/main/tutorials/Tutorial%201%20-%20Training%20and%20Evaluation%20of%20Logistic%20Regression%20on%20Encrypted%20Data.ipynb